# Bad DNS IP pushed down, map to another one?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns

Ubuntu 14.04 running as a VM in VirtualBox

The setup in my office pushes a nonfunctional DNS server down to my VM. This is a known issue for everyone in my office, and most people get around it by adding working DNS IPs to to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`.

Is there a way I can avoid having to add to that file, and instead do some sort of mapping like `if (ip == <bad DNS ip>) ip = <good DNS ip>`?

Comment: So you still need to add things to a file, just to a different file... Why has the office IT not done anything to fix this?

Comment: it appears to only affect ubuntu and its been long enough that i cant expect a fix anymore. i would like to not add to `resolv.conf` because my dns ips can change, so i dont want to always prepend the same internal subnet dns ips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using iptables to do this - something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp -d <bad DNS IP> --dport 53 -j DNAT --to <good DNS IP>:53
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <bad DNS IP> --dport 53 -j DNAT --to <good DNS IP>:53
```

Comment: thanks! that seemed to work! it seems to make these persist across restarts, i had to install something: `apt-get install iptables-persistent`. i then ran those commands you specified and exported them to my `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` by running `iptables-save` (because manually writing the exact format for the iptables-persistent rules file was tricky for a newbie like me).